# tsql: need help with returning latest record from a table

Tags: t-sql

If I have data like following:

```
CustID, CustDate, CustCode
===========================
123     12/1/10     a
123     12/2/10     b
456     12/3/10     c
456     12/4/10     d
789     12/5/10     3
```

How would I write the query that would return the latest record for that customer within that table?

Result should be..

```
CustID, CustDate, CustCode
===========================
123     12/2/10     b
456     12/4/10     d
789     12/5/10     3
```

Please help me write query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  CustId, CustDate, CustCode
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT * FROM MyTable AS a_MyTable
    WHERE a_MyTable.CustId = MyTable.CustId
      AND a_MyTable.CustDate > MyTable.CustDate
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select CustId, CustDate, CustCode
From Table As T
Where CustDate = (
                    Select Max(T1.CustDate)
                    From Table As T1
                    Where T1.CustID = T.CustID
                    )
```